Renaming LWC - Post Renaming
When you rename the LWC Component and deploy it from VS Code, what will happen to the existing LWC Component with the older name?
-- Will it be deleted automatically and replaced with the new name?
-- We need to manually delete the LWC Component with the older name?
Thanks In Advance!

Refer to this: https://developer.salesforce.com/tools/vscode/en/deploy-changes/metadata-operations#rename-component

Thanks @TusharJadav! I already looked into that document before posting my question. My question is if you change/rename the LWC components name and deploy it to your org, What will happen then?? The existing LWC component name will be overriden or new LWC component will get created with the new name and the existing one with the old name will be auto deleted or the existing one with the old name will exists we need to delete that manually.

Depends how you deploy. If you use source tracking with the SF CLI it will get deleted. Most other cases will leave the old component on the org too.
